# How can I run a quick script on lots of remote servers?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, cloud

I need to restart apache on a dozen servers.  I can log into each one and do it or I can have one script on the first one do it for me.  Can you help me out?

`Server 1` has access to all the other servers through known hosts.

Manually I can run this:

```
ssh user@server2
service httpd restart
exit

...

ssh user@server100
service httpd restart
exit
```

How can I script this to run from server 1 to restart all my servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for I in $(seq 2 100) ; 
do 
   ssh user@server$I 'service httpd restart' ;
done
```

Comment: Thanks.  That one liner will come in very handy for more than this use case.

Answer (score 2):

```
for server in user@server2 user@server3; do
    ssh $server service httpd restart
done
```

If you wanna generate hostnames take a look on `seq` utility.

Answer (score 1):

`pdsh -R exec server[2-100] service httpd restart`